# When I try to install tensorflow I met an error

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu-16.04

OS: Ubuntu 16.04.
python version is 2.7.12.
pip version is 9.0.1.
When I type

> pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl

as the guide tells, however I get the following output
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
and I don't know much about the error, because I try to ping 'storage.googleapis.com', I find I can receive the responce data. Hope anyone can help me. Thanks very much!

edit: add the error message.

```
Collecting tensorflow==0.5.0 from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fe5752fd710>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',)': /tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fe57420a750>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',)': /tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fe57420a850>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',)': /tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fe57420ae90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',)': /tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fe57420a190>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',)': /tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lwj/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/lwj/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/home/lwj/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/home/lwj/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/home/lwj/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 620, in _prepare_file
    session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
  File "/home/lwj/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 821, in unpack_url
    hashes=hashes
  File "/home/lwj/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 659, in unpack_http_url
    hashes)
  File "/home/lwj/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 853, in _download_http_url
    stream=True,
  File "/home/lwj/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lwj/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 386, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lwj/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/lwj/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 596, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lwj/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 47, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/home/lwj/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 487, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='storage.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl (Caused by NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fe57420af50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',))
```

> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSLml.png

Comment: It is much more useful to us if you copy paste the error instead of providing a screenshot. What is the reason for installing such an old version of tensorflow?

Comment: Just enter the url in a browser or try "wget https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl" works for me. Smells like a connection issue (which you can also derive from the network is unreachable error)

Comment: `Max reties exceeded`... You tried a bunch, and now the site is preventing access. Try tomorrow

Comment: sorry, I will edit it. And I guess it might be the network problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for anyone who helps me. I slove this question by using

> sudo pip install tensorflow

instead of using the network address. Luckily, it works.